# Cookie “scop” has been rejected for invalid domain

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

i try many times, but still have no solution for my problem
please help me...
i use reverse proxy on node.js and see this error - Cookie “scop” has been rejected for invalid domain.
how to fix this?
**my app.js**

```
async function bootstrap() {
    const config = (0, config_init_1.default)();
    
    console.log(`[ReverseEngine] Mirror website ${config.target}`);
    if (config.proxy)
        console.log(`[ReverseEngine] Using proxy agent ${config.proxy.hostname}:${config.proxy.port}`);
    app.use("/verify", proxy(config.target_verify, {
        userResDecorator: (0, responceInterceptorVerify_1.default)(config),
        userResHeaderDecorator: (0, headersInterceptor_1.default)(config),
        proxyReqOptDecorator: (proxyReqOpts) => {
            if (config.proxy)
                proxyReqOpts.agent = new tor_agent_1.TorProxyAgent(config.proxy);
            return proxyReqOpts;
        },
    }));

// need cookieParser middleware before we can do anything with cookies



// let static middleware do its job

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(proxy(config.target, {
        proxyReqBodyDecorator: function (bodyContent, srcReq) {
            srcReq.body = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(bodyContent.toString("utf-8")));
            return bodyContent;
        },
        userResDecorator: (0, responseInterceptor_1.default)(config),
        userResHeaderDecorator: (0, headersInterceptor_1.default)(config),
        proxyReqOptDecorator: (proxyReqOpts) => {
            if (config.proxy)
                proxyReqOpts.agent = new tor_agent_1.TorProxyAgent(config.proxy);
            return proxyReqOpts;
        },
    }));
    await app.listen(config.port);
    console.log(`[ReverseEngine] Started on ${config.port} port`);
}
bootstrap();
```

i was try all what i find on stackowerflow=((